# How to divide json array in hive table into batches the size of a given batch size?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, hive

For example, at the input we have hive table like this:

| id | entities |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"a": "a1", "b": "b1"}, {"a": "a2", "b": "b2"}, {"a": "a3", "b": "b3"}, {"a": "a4", "b": "b4"}, {"a": "a5", "b": "b5"}] |
| 2 | [{"c": "c1", "d": "d1"}, {"c": "c2", "d": "d2"}, {"c": "c3", "d": "d3"}, {"c": "c4", "d": "d4"}, {"c": "c5", "d": "d5"}] |

And with batchSize = 3 we should get no more than three elements in each array, like this:

| id | entities |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"a": "a1", "b": "b1"}, {"a": "a2", "b": "b2"}, {"a": "a3", "b": "b3"}] |
| 1 | [{"a": "a4", "b": "b4"}, {"a": "a5", "b": "b5"}] |
| 2 | [{"c": "c1", "d": "d1"}, {"c": "c2", "d": "d2"}, {"c": "c3", "d": "d3"}] |
| 2 | [{"c": "c4", "d": "d4"}, {"c": "c5", "d": "d5"}] |

With batchSize = 2 no more than two elements in arrays:

| id | entities |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"a": "a1", "b": "b1"}, {"a": "a2", "b": "b2"}] |
| 1 | [{"a": "a3", "b": "b3"}, {"a": "a4", "b": "b4"}] |
| 1 | [{"a": "a5", "b": "b5"}] |
| 2 | [{"c": "c1", "d": "d1"}, {"c": "c2", "d": "d2"}] |
| 2 | [{"c": "c3", "d": "d3"}, {"c": "c4", "d": "d4"}] |
| 2 | [{"c": "c5", "d": "d5"}] |

Are there any built-ins in the hive or can you suggest a spark udf?

I tried to write udf - but I don't know how to make it return several lines with subarrays instead of one. Because udf usually does some operations with several columns and returns the result, but I don’t know how to split the array into several lines with subarrays.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `slice` function to get subarrays and then `explode` to get multiple rows.

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = // input

val batchSize = 2 

df.select('id, explode(expr(
    s"transform(sequence(1, size(entities), $batchSize)," +
      s" s-> slice(entities, s, $batchSize)) ")))
    .show(false)

+---+--------------------+
|id |col                 |
+---+--------------------+
|1  |[[a1, b1], [a2, b2]]|
|1  |[[a3, b3], [a4, b4]]|
|1  |[[a5, b5]]          |
+---+--------------------+
```